# Need helping Fixing ToolBar issue in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-toolbar

The toolbar is in Purple above the Tablayout in my XML file.

[image]

However, here as you can see for some reason the toolbar which is supposed to be the MainActivity and the Settings in those 3 dots, now for some reason the toolbar is in between the MainActivity toolbar and the tab layout.

[image]

How to fix this? I want the purple toolbar to disappear from the middle. What can I do?

Comment: Have you tried to remove or set the visibility of toolbar as gone on the xml?

Comment: Just set the Toolbar visibility to gone either in xml or programatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove this toolbar the simplest way to do it is set it visibility as gone. This property will make the toolbar invisible and it doesn't take any space on the layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Didn't even think about doing that. Thank you.